# Issue with installation of dlib

Tags: dlib

I am trying to install dlib with

```
pip install dlib
```

and I ma getting this error message . Any advice on how to help solve this issue ;

```
C:\Users\xxxxx>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
  Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp97einqqvpip-wheel- --python-tag  cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-z3ahr2ci/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\wb421558\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-98zm2ie0-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.6 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-z3ahr2ci/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.6', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-98zm2ie0-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z3ahr2ci\dlib\
```

Answer (score 0):

install visual studio with Visual C++ tools for CMake  and then try to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not developing in C++, you would need a redistributable for the language installed on your PC.

You do not have to install the whole Visual Studio for this. Just download a build tool for the 64bit arch from the following link and install it. [Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Build Tool](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16)

Try running the dlib installation after that and it should work